# How to access objects without using if then or case swtich [javascript]

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

So I created an object prototype like this:

```
function myObjProto(one, two, three) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
    this.three = three;  };
```

Then created a bunch of objects like this:

```
let myObj1 = new myObjProto (
    /* one */ "one", 
    /* two */ "two", 
    /* three */ "three" );
let myObj2 = new myObjProto (
    /* one */ "one", 
    /* two */ "two", 
    /* three */ "three" );
```

I have a variable that is changing (myObj1, myObj2, etc) and I know that one way to access the values is to say

```
let myVar = "myObj";

let var1;
let var2;
let var3;

if (myVar == myObj1){
    var1 = myObj1.one;
    var2 = myObj1.two;
    var3 = myObj1.three;
}
else {
    var1 = myObj2.one;
    var2 = myObj2.two;
    var3 = myObj3.three;
}
```

But there has to be a better way. I have 7 objects!

I tried something like this:

```
var1 = myVar.one;
var2 = myVar.two;
var3 = myVar.three;
```

But all I got was "undefined." Please help.

(The full example is [here on JSbin](http://jsbin.com/wuhecez/edit?js,console))

Comment: Could it be you are looking for `myVar instanceof myObj1`? On the other hand, if the properties are the same, there is no need for you to do the ifs, as you seem to access the same variable names for the object

Comment: your jsbin link is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object for all types and take the type as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets.

```
var Dwarf = new race(),
    Elf = new race(),
    Gnome = new race(),
    HalfElf = new race(),
    HalfOrc = new race(),
    Halfling = new race(),
    Human = new race(),
    types = { Dwarf, Elf, Gnome, HalfElf, HalfOrc, Halfling, Human },
    type = 'Halfling';


// access:
types[type].language
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can use object deconstruction, but the variables need to match

`const {one, two, three} = myVar == myObj1 ? myObj1 : myObj2;`

Now one, two, three will be the value of the correct object

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The use of a ternary operator is in essence an if, just shorthand, Nina gives a very nice answer. The code you present, might be a one liner, but that doesn't make it easier to read for the OP